How to make DNS server for Retrocomputing
I'd like some help creating a retro DNS server, and I have a few questions:
How do I get the pages in the wayback and put them in my DNS?
How do I point the server to mount these pages?
I would like to do something similar to UCANET, but with pages only from my country.
Does anyone have any ideas?

This question is more about doing DNS - which is modern - than anything necessarily retro. I'd suggest you go to either the main Stack Exchange or perhaps the Computer Science SE.

By Wayback, do you mean the Internet Archive's Wayback Machine? If so, this is a whole bunch of different questions. I recommend asking a high-level "what do I need to do to achieve this?"-type question on… [su], probably? Then asking the follow-up questions on specific sites, as appropriate. (Some of those questions might be appropriate here, for example if you're trying to get an SSL configuration that works with Netscape 4.0, we can tell you which configuration you might need.)

What does it mean to “get the pages in the wayback and put them in my DNS”?

I think what the op is trying to achieve is to set up a proxy that, when asked for www.somewebsite.org, provides the archived version of that site as of a given date, creating the illusion of surfing the web in 1997 (or whatever).

I don't think this exists.  I think CNAMEs or ALIASs only redirect whole domains to whole domains, not to URLs.  So what you might want is a proxy, and even then it would probably need intelligence or a huge database since individual webpages have individual snapshot dates in the archive.

@marmelucos: Is this what you're looking for? https://github.com/TomKTW/dev.kobalt.wmps https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=J4fwz7OFp6Q (I knew I had seen something like this before, somewhere.)

@MichaelGraf That’s a question the asker should answer, not you second-guess.

I'm not quite sure what you're going for here:

DNS is the mechanism by which domain names (like www.stackexchange.com) are translated into IP addresses (like, in IPv4, 123.45.67.89). Ideally, for the internet as a whole to work, this translation should be the same for everyone. However, with your own DNS server, you can create your own mapping. Note that, when retrieving a web page, this only affects the domain name part of the URL, not the path that follows.
UCANET uses its own DNS to create a separate "retro internet". However, it's separate only in terms of domain names; all the pages in this "retro internet" are hosted on regular (IPv4) servers, and reachable via the normal internet if you know the IP address. These pages are not retrieved from the Internet Archive's Wayback machine.
If you want to serve pages from the Wayback machine instead, just remapping the domain name using your own DNS won't help you. If your goal is that, when browsing www.somewebsite.org, you get the archived version of that site as of a given date, creating the illusion of surfing the web in 1997 (or whatever), you need a proxy that figures out the Wayback URL and serves you that page.
Fortunately, it seems like someone has already built such a proxy, the Wayback Machine Proxy Server. There's also a demonstration video.

